# Local variable 'result' might be referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function, exception, scope, pycharm

With a flow like this:

```
def func():
    try:
        result = calculate()
    finally:
        try:
            cleanup()
        except Exception:
            pass
    return result
```

There is a warning about *Local variable 'result' might be referenced before assignment*:

[image: wat]

But I can't really see how that's possible. One of these must be true:

- `calculate()` raises an exception --> the return statement will never get reached, so result is not referenced again
- `calculate()` does not raise an exception --> result is successfully assigned, and the return statement returns that value

How would you ever get `result` referenced before assignment? Is there an implementation of `calculate` and `cleanup` which could demonstrate that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a false positive of PyCharms warning heuristics. As per the Python specification, the code behaves as you describe and `result` can only be reached when set.

---

According to 8.4 in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html):

> If the finally clause executes a return, break or continue statement, the saved exception is discarded:

```
>>> def f():
...     try:
...         1/0
...     finally:
...         return 42
...
>>> f()
42
```

The Python interpreter will ignore the exception that was caused by `calculate()` if the `finally` block contains a `return`, `break`, or `continue` statement.

This means that with the implementation you provided, where the `finally` block has neither of the words specified above, the exception caused by `calculate` won't be discarded, so the `result` variable won't be referenced, meaning that this warning is useless.

Comment: `X -> Y` doesn't necessarily imply `not X -> not Y`. The contra-positive here would be more like "_If the saved exception is not discarded, then the finally clause has not executed a return, break or continue statement_", which doesn't seem to help much for this question

Comment: @nooboverflow X -> Y does imply not X -> not Y if the set of X is exhaustive. The Python spec (and many other languages) usually only makes positive assertions; the inverse is infeasible since there are infinitely many, or at least unfeasibly many, negative cases.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If we're about pure mathematical logic meaning, `X -> Y` in fact does not imply anything if `X` is false, the only way implication is False is if X is True and Y is not.

Comment: I guess you are right, this documentation isn't making much of a difference. but now we do know that OP is correct - this is a false warning, but this kind of flow is discouraged by PEP8. I think that this is enough to resolve this question, isn't it?

Comment: @LITzman What part of PEP8 discourages that?

Comment: Quote from the PEP: "Use of the flow control statements return/break/continue within the finally suite of a try...finally, where the flow control statement would jump outside the finally suite, is discouraged. This is because such statements will implicitly cancel any active exception that is propagating through the finally suite"

Comment: @LITzman That doesn't apply to my code at all - **I'm not using return/break/continue within a finally suite**. So while that part of PEP8 certainly applies to the code snippet from [8.4](https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) which was reproduced in this answer, it doesn't apply to the code shown in the question.